# extract text from second div by text beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

A have below html code. Need to extract text4 based on "text3" value

```
    <div class="main">
<ul>
<li>
<div class="1"> text1 </div>
<div class="2"> text2 </div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="1"> text3</div>
<div class="2"> text4</div>
</li>
</ul></div>
```

I used this code, but its not working. Am I missing something or there is simpler solution for this?

```
a.find_next_sibling('div')[0]
for a in soup.find_all('div', text='text3')
```

Comment: if you use `text='text3'`, it has to be an exact match, which in your case in the example theres a white space ` text3`, which then, you can use next sibling after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identify the tag using css selector and use `find_next('div')`

```
html='''   <div class="main">
<ul>
<li>
<div class="1"> text1 </div>
<div class="2"> text2 </div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="1"> text3</div>
<div class="2"> text4</div>
</li>
</ul></div>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
print(soup.select_one('.main div:contains(text3)').find_next('div').text.strip())
```

---

Or you can use regular expression re.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
html='''   <div class="main">
<ul>
<li>
<div class="1"> text1 </div>
<div class="2"> text2 </div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="1"> text3</div>
<div class="2"> text4</div>
</li>
</ul></div>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
print(soup.find('div', class_='main').find('div',text=re.compile("text3")).find_next('div').text.strip())
```

Answer (score 1):

if you use `text='text3'`, it has to be an exact match, which in your case in the example theres a white space `text3`. So you'll need to find `text3` as a substring or contained within an element, and once you do that, you can get that next `<div>` element

```
html = '''    <div class="main">
<ul>
<li>
<div class="1"> text1 </div>
<div class="2"> text2 </div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="1"> text3</div>
<div class="2"> text4</div>
</li>
</ul></div>'''


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for a in soup.find_all('div', text=re.compile(r'text3')):
    print (a.find_next('div').text.strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution

```
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc 
html = '''   <div class="main">
<ul>
<li>
<div class="1"> text1 </div>
<div class="2"> text2 </div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="1"> text3</div>
<div class="2"> text4</div>
</li>
</ul></div>'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
div = doc.getElementByText('text3',tag='div').getNext('div')
print (div) # {'class': '2', 'tag': 'div', 'html': 'text4'}
print (div.text) # text4
```